# XML tags in database

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml, eval

I need to load a ton of XML feeds and save the information to database. I have no control over the XML fields but they generally contain an unique id, a title, a currency, price and duration.

Code below is working fine just for 1 feed:

```
function process_xml_file($path, $adv_id)
{

$xml = simplexml_load_file($path, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

$data = array();
$finished = array();
$counter = 0;

// loop through all items
foreach($xml->product as $product)
{
    $product_id = strip_tags((string)$product->productID);

    if(!in_array($product_id, $finished))
    {
        $country = $product->xpath('./extra/field[@name="country"]');
        $data[$counter]['country'] = strip_tags((string)$country[0]);

        $data[$counter]['title'] = strip_tags((string)$product->name);
        $data[$counter]['currency'] = strip_tags((string)$product->price['currency']);
        $data[$counter]['price'] = strip_tags((string)$product->price);

        $duration = $product->xpath('./extra/field[@name="duration"]');
        $data[$counter]['duration'] = strip_tags((string)$duration[0]);

        // add this product to the finished array, we want to exclude duplicates
        $finished[$counter] = $product_id;

        $counter++;
    }
}
return $data; // the data will be saved to database in an other method
```

}

I was thinking of saving things like prod_id and xpath('./extra/field[@name="country"]') in a database so I can easily retrieve the values of different feed fields using eval(). I know eval() is evil, and am open to better suggestions. I'm the only one handling this kind of data, so eval() danger might be somewhat smaller than usual.

Retrieving the product_id and title works fine, the problem is in country and duration using xpath, eval() will throw an error like:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"xpath('./additional/field[@na' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\feed.php(220) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Example:

```
// simple xml object of all products
$children = $xml->children();

$country = $tag['country']; // $tag is from the db

// loop through all products
foreach($children as $product)
{
    $id = strip_tags($product->$product_id);

    $country = $product->$country;
    eval("\$country2 = \$product->\"{$country}\";");

    echo $country2;
}
```

My database table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_feeds_xml_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `feed_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `country` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `product_id` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `feed_id` (`feed_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Results from the table:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [feed_id] => 1
    [country] => xpath('./additional/field[@name="country"]')
    [product_id] => productID
    [title] => name
    [currency] => price['currency']
    [price] => price
    [duration] => xpath('./additional/field[@name="duration"]')
)
```

XML feed example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<products>
    <product>
    <productID>32934</productID>
    <name>Cruise Antillen en Zuid-Amerika &amp; strand Curaçao</name>
    <price currency="EUR">1405.00</price>
    <extra>
        <field name="country">Panama</field>
        <field name="duration">12</field>
    </extra>
    </product>
    ..
    etc.
    ..
</products>
```

**My question is: how can I make this function work for all feeds?** Keep in mind that in other feeds the prod_id or the country tag is named completely different.

I can't figure it out, have struggled with this for days and couldn't find answers on this forum.

Suggestions to eval() alternatives are welcome too!

Please be clear in your answers, since I'm a novice in php.

Comment: even though there is a wall of text i still dont get what you want

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need eval()? If you store the xpath expressions that retrieve the values you need for each feed, you just need to retrieve that expression and pass it to the DOM system, e.g.

Database:

```
feeds (id, url)
feed_xpath (id, feed_id, value_being_fetched, xpath_expression)
```

Pull up a particular feed, e.g. `http://example.com/feed.xml`, then pull up its related xpath stuff:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($feed_url);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$values = array();
foreach($feeds as $feed) { // $feeds being selected from the feeds_xpath table
    $nodelist = $xpath->query($feed['xpath'])
    foreach($nodelist as $node) {
        $array[$feed['value_being_fetched']] = $node->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc B. I got your code working, but it only returns 1 row of results because of $array[$feed['value_being_fetched']]. How can I change the $array to sort all results neatly with a unique id (for example the productID from the xml file) ?